# I Need To Scroll Inside a Drop Down Box

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium, i Was Automating, But in That Drop down Menu i need  to Click on The Element Which is Hidden Down.
It scrolls whole page down i want only specific dropdown scrolled down not page.

HTML Code For The Full Div :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu drop_Loc" role="menu" style="display: none;" xpath="1"> <li> 
<a href="carle_place.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-fort icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0px 8px;"></span> <span class="nav_icon_heading">Carle Place</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="Selling-a-car-cutler-bay.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon2-cutlerbay icon-left" style="font-size: 24px;padding: 7px 8px;"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">Cutler Bay</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="Daytona.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-daytona icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">Daytona</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="Fort_lauderdale.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-fort icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> <span class="nav_icon_heading">Fort Lauderdale</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="Sell-my-car-longwood.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-orlando icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">Longwood</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="Melbourne.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-melbourne icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">Melbourne</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="miami.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-miami icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">Miami</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="Orlando.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-orlando icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">Orlando</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="St_James.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-daytona icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">St James</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="Treasure_coast.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-treasure_coast icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">Stuart</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="Tampa.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-treasure_coast icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">Tampa</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
<a id="last-child-location" href="West_palm_beach.aspx" target="_self"> 
<span class="icon-palm_beach icon-left" style="font-size: 40px;padding: 0 8px"></span> 
<span class="nav_icon_heading">West Palm Beach</span> 
</a> 
</li> 
</ul>
```

[image: Scroll Down Image]

i Tried With These Code,

`By Stuart = By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/nav[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]/ul[1]/li[10]/a[1]/span[2]")`;

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(Stuart);
                je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
                Thread.sleep(4000);
```

The Above Code is Working,But it is Scrolling The Dropdown aswell as Webpage Also.

Please Sort Me out This Guys.

Comment: just apply overflow: auto for the role="menu element or its class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is right i didn't find any problem in your code it should scroll till that element is visible.

Don't use absolute xpath, it's good practice to always use [dynamic xpaths](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/).

Please try below code,

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);').then(function () {
    page.saveButton.click();
})
```

Comment: You are Right, Can You Give me a Clear View? @swapnil wandhe

Answer (score 0):

You can also use action class of selenium for scroll,
for that you will need to import it.

`import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;`

```
WebElement menuItem = Driver.findElement(menuItemPath);
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.moveToElement(menuItem);
action.perform();
menuItem.click();
```